# Master/Detail layout not rendering

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to make an app that fetches a book list from an API and displays it on the master list and, upon clicking, it displays the details. It works fine with mobiles, but I can't get it to work with tablets and since there's no error I can't find out where I went wrong.

**On tablets it renders as if on a phone instead of rendering the two pane view.**

I'm using a single activity with fragments.

"Main" activity:

```
public class ItemListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private boolean isTwoPane = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

    determinePaneLayout();

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if(isTwoPane){

        //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.master_dual, new ItemsListFragment()).commit();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.flDetailContainer, new ItemDetailFragment()).commit();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new ItemsListFragment()).commit();

    } else {

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new ItemsListFragment()).commit();
    }
}

private void determinePaneLayout() {
    FrameLayout fragmentItemDetail = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flDetailContainer);
    // If there is a second pane for details
    if (fragmentItemDetail != null) {
        isTwoPane = true;
    }
}
```

Item List Fragment:

```
public class ItemsListFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<Book> bookList;
private ArrayList<String> bookNames;
private ArrayAdapter<Book> bookArrayAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> bookNamesAdapter;
private ApiInterface apiInterface;
private ListView lvItems;
private static final String bookKey = "newBook";
private static Book nBook;

public ItemsListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items_list,
            container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    lvItems = view.findViewById(R.id.lvItems);

    bookNames = new ArrayList<>();

    //bookNames.add(0, "Gabriel");

    apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<ArrayList<Book>> call = apiInterface.getBooks();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Book>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Book>> call, Response<ArrayList<Book>> response) {

            bookList = new ArrayList<>();
            bookList = response.body();

            bookArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, bookList);

            lvItems.setAdapter(bookArrayAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Book>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            nBook = bookList.get(i);

            if(view.findViewById(R.id.flDetailContainer) != null){

                ItemListActivity.fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flDetailContainer, ItemDetailFragment.newInstance(nBook)).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            } else {

                ItemListActivity.fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, ItemDetailFragment.newInstance(nBook)).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }


        }
    });
}`
```

Item Detail Fragment:

```
public class ItemDetailFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String bookKey = "newBook";
private static Book nBook;
private TextView title;
private TextView isbn;
private TextView currency;
private TextView price;
private TextView author;

public static ItemDetailFragment newInstance(Book book) {
    ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(bookKey, book);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        nBook = (Book)getArguments().getSerializable(bookKey);
        Log.v("BundleOK", "BundleOK");
    } else {
        Log.v("Bundle Nulo", "Bundle nulo");
    }
}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail,
                container, false);
        // Return view
        return view;
    }

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    title = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    isbn = view.findViewById(R.id.tvIsbn);
    currency = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCurrency);
    price = view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
    author = view.findViewById(R.id.tvAuthor);

    title.setText(nBook.getTitle());
    isbn.setText("ISBN: " + nBook.getIsbn());
    currency.setText("Currency: "+ nBook.getCurrency());
    price.setText("Price: "+ String.valueOf((long)nBook.getPrice()/100));
    author.setText("Autor: "+nBook.getAuthor());

}
```

XML for dual pane:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:showDividers="middle"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentItemsList"
    android:name="gabrielgomes.studio.com.itemretrieve.ItemsListFragment"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_items_list" />

<View android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flDetailContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3" />
```

XML for the Main Activity (Item List Activity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

XML for the Item Detail Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/baskervillebt"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Item Title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvIsbn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/baskervilleitalicbt"
    android:text="Item Body"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvIsbn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/baskervilleitalicbt"
    android:text="Price"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCurrency"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPrice"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/baskervilleitalicbt"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"

    android:text="Currency"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAuthor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvCurrency"
    android:fontFamily="@font/baskervilleitalicbt"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:text="Author"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

I've been cracking my head for 5 days now, so any help is really appreciated! I tried a number of tutorials and searched SO thoroughly but no go!

Cheers!

Comment: Post the layout for single page including its full name. E,g: `activity_main.xml`

Comment: What is not working ?? Its getting crashed or anything else ? Please specify

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two copies activity_item_list.xml layout file and one is res/layout/ folder and another one is in res/layout-sw600dp/ folder.

sw600dp --> Screen width above 600dp use this layout else if less than 600dp use default layout file.

And also you make sure keep same attribute ids same in both the layout files.